# Hot and Neutral on Same Circuit Breaker

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci

I just installed a new GFCI and it keeps shutting off even though I connected it properly. 
I traced the wires and found that the neutral was connected to the same Circuit Breaker as the hot. WHY? And how can I fix this so my GFCI will work?[image]

Comment: What loads does this breaker serve? Also, what amperage is said breaker?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have HOT-HOT here?  Just because the wire is white doesn't mean someone didn't hook it up to the hot and that's what it looks like to me from the photo.

Comment: This is leading to an outlet that I changed to a GFCI. 20amp. I thought it was a hot white wire and tried attaching both to a hot and it immediately shut off.

Comment: @SheenaMB -- what was plugged into this outlet?  Can you post photos of the face of the old outlet, even?

Comment: @SheenaMB also, can you post a photo of the label on the inside of the door to your breaker box please?

Comment: I threw the old outlet away and there is no sticker or labeling of any kind on the door of the breaker box. Had to turn on/off each circuit breaker to figure out which switch went to which outlet.

Comment: @SheenaMB -- can you post a photo of the breaker box as a whole then please? And fish the old outlet out of the trash? (Unless the trash has gone out the door already, of course)

Answer (score 3):

### You'll need a 20A *GFCI breaker* for this

What you are looking at there is a 240V circuit on a two-pole breaker; both the black and white wires are hots, but from *opposite legs of your service* (one pulls one way, the other pulls the other way), which is why connecting them both to the LINE HOT on the GFCI receptacle tripped the breaker (as it should have, to stop the game of electrical tug-of-war you inadvertently created).

As a result, you can't use a GFCI receptacle on this circuit at all, as 240V GFCI receptacles simply are not made; instead, you need to use the correct GFCI *circuit breaker* for your panel to provide protection to a regular (non-GFCI) 240V receptacle of the correct configuration (and a Sharpie, black electrical tape, or the likes to remark that white wire in your picture as a hot wire).

And by the way, the correct receptacle for your application is a NEMA 6-20T; if the receptacle there already wasn't a NEMA 6, it'll need to be replaced with one, lest you leave a 240V boobytrap for the next poor bloke who has to service this circuit!

Answer (score 1):

### That *was* a 240V circuit

The problem was, it was a different style of outlet, and you didn't notice that.

In the future, don't throw any parts away until the project is done.

[image]

It was one of the two on the right.  (Or at least, it was *supposed to be*. Sometimes lazy people running grow lights or Bitcoin miners just use the standard recep and put 240V on it).

You did not realize that the circuit was for 240V.

### You actually want a 120V circuit, apparently.

Now, I gather that you don't give any care about running 240V anything, and what you actually want is the one on the left, but with GFCI.  Am I right?

So that won't be terribly hard.  You're going to need to go back into your service panel where you took the picture, grab a flashlight and shut off the main breaker.  **Parts of the panel will still be hot; don't touch anything you don't absolutely need to**.

Then you see that white wire on the breaker?  Move that to the neutral bar.   The bar with a whole bunch of other white wires.   It must have its own screw; it can't share a screw *even if you see other wires sharing screws*.  Neutrals can never share screws (3 grounds probably can, if your panel labeling says they can).

At that point you should be able to wire up the GFCI normally and have it work.  Be prepared for the possibility that you fried this GFCI and anything you had plugged into it at the time.

### No no, I really need a 240V circuit

If took a close look at the pool pump, boat lift, tanning bed or European coffeemaker and thought "Wait. That does have a different plug than all my other stuff.  I do need one of the ones on the right."  Then you need to follow ThreePhaseEel's advice above.

A $80 GFCI circuit breaker is the only possible way to GFCI protect this 240V load. It is **mandatory** as of NEC 2020 (which only Massachusetts has adopted, so far, but 44 states will in the next 2 years).  It **is a good idea** in a kitchen or anyplace with water e.g. [poolside or dockside](https://www.electricshockdrowning.org).

Answer (score 0):

The White Wire Is A Hot Wire.  It is not neutral.  Black electrical tape should have been rapped around the end of the white wire signifying it's a hot wire, not neutral.