# Wrong wiring color used for 240V appliance (white/black instead of red/black)

Tags: electrical, wiring

We had the electrical system in our house upgraded as part of a remodel. While investigating an electrical issue, I noticed that our AC unit (which is rated 240 volt / 25 amp) appears to be wired with the wrong color wiring: it uses white/black wiring instead of red/black wiring. I'm certain it's 240V because I measured between the white/black terminals within the breaker box, and the label on the AC unit also says it's a 240V appliance.

How egregious is it to wire a 240V appliance using white/black wiring? Should I ask the electrician to redo this piece of wiring? (The gauge of the wire seems to be correct -- 10AWG -- given that it's a 25 amp appliance.)

Comment: Are you in the US or Canada?

Comment: This is in the US.

Comment: @Alaska Man, I realize this might seem like a non-issue, but it seems like a potential safety hazard to me. AFAIK the convention is white==neutral=="won't electrocute you". But in the case of our wiring, the white wire can electrocute you.

Comment: Is this a cable or wires in a conduit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a cable assembly (like NM or MC cable) NEC 200.7(C) allows re-identifying the white wire for use as an ungrounded conductor by tape, paint, or other permanent means.

If it pipe and wire then you need to re-pull the wire. Usually it doesn't have to be red, but red is good, it can't be grey, white, or green and it's easier to not pick through details and avoid anything with stripes.

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark the white wire as red and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

> AFAIK the convention is white==neutral=="won't electrocute you".

You need to know further. If it's a 240V only appliance (no neutral, no 120V loads, just 240V and ground) fed by a cable, the fact of the matter is that white will be hot, because they don't make two wire cable that's red/black in standard household wiring.

A detailed approach will apply black or red tape to the white wire at the termination to indicate that it's hot, but this is actually quite rare, since the fact that it's connected to a two-pole breaker makes that "obvious" at the panel, and the fact that it's connected to a 240V appliance makes it "obvious" at the appliance. But I personally would apply the red tape, though I doubt I'd call back an electrician and expect them to do it for me.

If there's a conduit run, the hot wires should be any of the hot colors (black red brown blue yellow orange purple...) and not white or gray or green - but only if there's conduit, not cable.

Answer (score 1):

What NoSparksPlease said.  It's perfectly legit to use /2 cable (black-white) to hook up a 240V-only load (hot-hot-ground). **However, you *MUST*  re-mark the white wire with tape or paint** to indicate that it is a hot, [so **this** doesn't happen](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/190999/hot-and-neutral-on-same-circuit-breaker).

A long time ago, this marking could be omitted *if the usage was obvious*. Code was changed to "always", because "obvious" is a problem for novices.  Some good-ole-boy electricians refuse to respect that change because it benefits DIYers, who they think ought to stay the heck out of boxes and hire an electrician.

So if your work is old enough, it's grandfathered and doesn't need a mark.  However, give it one just the same :)

Now, as NoSparksPlease says, in conduit you're not allowed to re-mark white wires to make them hots.  (you can re-mark white wires all you like, but that won't make them hots).  However, sometimes, conduit novices don't realize this, and go ahead and use white on switch loops because that's what the website said to do.